# SmsManager RESULT_ERROR_LIMIT_EXCEEDED

Tags: android, smsmanager

I have this app which sends SMS, lately, some of the users have been complaining about receiving `RESULT_ERROR_LIMIT_EXCEEDED` when sending SMS.

The documentation states `"Failed because we reached the sending queue limit."` I haven't managed to find anything related to this error online as it has been added in API 27 and I believe it is kinda new and the description doesn't really give enough insight.

How can this error be fixed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find and reproduce the error by digging inside the android source code: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/telephony/+/master/src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/SMSDispatcher.java

Here it states:

```
     /**
     * Deny sending an SMS if the outgoing queue limit is reached. Used when the message
     * must be confirmed by the user due to excessive usage or potential premium SMS detected.
     * @param tracker the SmsTracker for the message to send
     * @return true if the message was denied; false to continue with send confirmation
     */
  private boolean denyIfQueueLimitReached(SmsTracker tracker)
```

To fix it, you need to allow your app to send premium sms by going into settings -> apps -> top menu (3 dots) -> Special access -> Use premium sms messages services -> always allow/ask, for the app in cause.

Hope it will help some of you with answers.

Comment: I cannot found this option to set premium sms messages services

Answer (score 0):

In my case the settings of the FileProvider in my Manifast file wasn't correct.
I took time to find that out because RESULT_ERROR_LIMIT_EXCEEDED doesn't seem an error in the FileProvider... 
Anyways, now it is working for me.